# Scrollbar hidden in IE6 (css issue)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, scrollbar

I'm not a CSS guru and I'm seeking your help.

The following site www.jomea.com does not work properly in IE6.  You cannot scroll down the page and it gets cut off.

The web designer who worked on the html/css cannot fix and has been wasting my time for the past couple of months.

style sheet for default page: ~/styles/jomea.css
style sheet for other page: ~/styles/jomea2.css

If anyone can figure out the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a significant part of this question is no longer available (or soon will not be), since the code is not included in the question but merely linked to elsewhere, I'm voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's one potential issue in ~/styles/jomea.css

```
ul.sponsored-results li ul { width:900px; margin-left:20px; overflow:hidden; }
```

Overflow is hidden on this item, not sure if this is the problem item but you could experiment with this property.

here's a couple potential issues in ~/styles/jomea2.css

```
#maincontainer {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:998px !important;
}

.content {width:570px; height:105px; overflow:hidden; padding:0 20px; text-align:left; color:#a0cb38; background:url(../images/faqs-bg.gif) no-repeat; }
```

Comment: I don't think this is it - after all, it's the whole body that is getting clipped.

Comment: well maincontainer also has it so does content. its worth a look man.

Comment: the #maincontainer is probably right on the money. My comment was referring to the top part of your answer.

Comment: However, the 2nd css file is not being loaded on the front page which also has the clipping problem.

Comment: @Pekka, Ok I must have edited the post, as you were commenting. No prob.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I tried setting the .content to overflow:auto.

The main content now appears but the footer is still hidden, and the navigation menu is bumped up.

Comment: @tito, The footer also has overflow:hidden

Comment: @gmcalab: i had to remove the overflow:hidden for both maincontent and the footer.  Thank you for the tip.  

My problem now is with the top navigation menu.  It keeps getting pushed above the horizontal green line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but a

```
body { overflow: auto }
```

should do the job. Alternatively, remove the `height: 100%` on the body and the html, but that could have unintended consequences in some places, you'd have to test.